# How to create API to insert data in MySQL passing json with dublicate keys

Tags: mysql, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am creating a REST API using Django-Rest-Framework to insert data in MySQL database. The table has column like - id, meta key, meta value i.e for particular id it can have duplicate meta keys and their corresponding meta value. I want to pass all the meta keys and meta values of corresponding id in  the json but it says Json does not support duplicate keys. What should be my approach to create the api which creates two rows in database  if I am passing 2 meta key and value for a same id?

The json looks like

"**order_item_id_2**":"154",
"**meta_key**":"_product_id",
"**meta_value**":"602",
"**meta_key**":"_variation_id",
"**meta_value**":"0"
"**meta_key**":"qty",
"**meta_value**":"20"

The table should look like:

[Final table should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7E2Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json field is not the right way to store this information. If you want to store duplicates you can try storing the data as a string.

The final table you show implies the will be 3 records from this json object. This doesn't make sense and you need to redesign your data model to solve your problem.